# Jetpack email sharing button to include image on email sent

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I am changing the message for the email sent by modifying the `sharedaddy.php` file and have now spent hours trying to include the image attached to the post on the email.

I tried adding the following two codes within the function below and had no luck displaying the images from the post in the email sent:

```
$content .=  wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
```

and

```
$content .=  wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'medium' );
```

into:

```
function sharing_email_send_post( $data ) {
    $content  = sprintf( __( 'Someone you know visited my website Living Healthy With Chocolate, http://livinghealthywithchocolate.com and thinks you may be interested in the following recipe:'."\n\n", 'jetpack' ), $data['name'], $data['source'] );
    $content .= $data['post']->post_title."\n";
    $content .= get_permalink( $data['post']->ID )."\n";
    wp_mail( $data['target'], ' '.$data['post']->post_title, $content );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_mail` does not support rich formatting, so you can't just embed the image in the body. It does, however, support attachments. If you read about the function, you'll see it has a parameter for attachments. Try hooking your attachment there instead:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

> **$attachments**
>   (string or array) (optional) Files to attach: a single filename, an array of filenames, or a newline-delimited string list of multiple filenames. (advanced)
>   Default: Empty

Edit:
So if you can figure out the attachment id of the image you want to reference, the `wp_mail` function will look more like this:

```
// check if featured image, use it if so
if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
} else {
    // otherwise use first post attachment
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'    => 1, 
    );
    foreach($attachments as $attachment_id_key => $attachment){
        $attachment_id = $attachment_id_key;
    }
}

wp_mail( 
    $data['target'], 
    $data['post']->post_title, 
    $content, 
    '',  
    wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id)
);
```

Comment: thanks GhostToast. I am sorry but I am not very good at this and I am not sure how to call the image. Can you give me an example? I want to include the featured image from the post on the email sent.

Comment: Updated answer to provide example.

Comment: is it possible to automatically include either the first image of the post or the featured image on the email sent? The emails are sending recipes to the recipient and a picture of the recipe is important. Here's is the website: livinghealthywithchocolate.com

Comment: Use `get_post_thumbnail_id()` to get the featured image ID.

Comment: ok so I changed it to wp_mail( $data['target'], ' '.$data['post']->post_title, $content, '', get_post_thumbnail_id() ); and it's not working.

Comment: last param sould be `wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id())`

Comment: sorry to bother you GhostToast, but the code is not attaching the image to the email sent. This time I changed it to: wp_mail( $data['target'], ' '.$data['post']->post_title, $content,'', wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()));

Comment: I've rewritten to put it all together in case you don't HAVE a featured image.

Comment: still not attaching the image to the email :( All my posts have a featured image, so that shouldn't be a problem but it's not working

Comment: It occurs to me you are referencing the referring post by this `$data['post']` object. Does it perhaps contain an `->ID` field? If so, use that anywhere an `ID` is expected. For example inside `get_post_thumbnail_id($data['post']->ID)`. Lemme know.

Comment: :( still nothing